# Capture input ID of the action button

Tags: shiny

I have a shiny application with action button

```
actionButton("show",class = "act_button", list(span(class="top left", "Model 1"), span(class="top right", Sys.time())))
```

Now, the ID of this action button is "show"
Is there a way to capture this ID when this button is clicked. Like

```
  observeEvent(input$show,{
    print(input$show)
  })
```

Actual ouput

```
[1] 1
attr(,"class")
[1] "integer"                "shinyActionButtonValue"
```

Expected output

```
show
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the name with `this.textContent` and id with `this.id`

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("show", "show", onclick = "Shiny.onInputChange('myclick', this.id)")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  observeEvent(input$show,{
    print(input$myclick)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: I tried. We do not get ID here

Comment: replace your action button with ````actionButton(inputId = "show", label = "label", onclick = "Shiny.onInputChange('myclick', this.textContent)")````

Comment: You will not get the ID

Comment: replace it with `this.id` as per update if you want the id and not the text